# Trying to put numbers into variables from an ifstream file

Tags: c++

Here is the input file:

```
Attendance: 5
Midterm: 20
Final: 20
Homework: 15
Projects: 40
Mc Pherson, David Patrick
Attendance: 12 15
Midterm: 80 100
Homework: 50 100
Homework: 60 100
Homework: 80 100
Project: 90 100
Project: 80 100
Project: 75 100
Final: 80 100
```

What I'm tasked with doing is taking this input file then putting it through a code that would output a gradebook. The part I'm currently stuck on is trying to get the numbers into variables and skipping the words prior to them. I tried using cin.ignore() but that doesn't work, or at least with my implementation of it.

How would I go about doing such a thing?

EDIT: For those, asking here is my code. The main file:

```
//This file tests out gradebook.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "gradebook.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
ifstream in ( "gradebook.txt" );
ostream out ( "grades.txt" );

while ( !in.fail() ) //tests to see if there are any more numbers coming in from resistors.h
{
    //process input
    gradebook ( in, cout );
}

in.close();
return 0;
}
```

Here is my other file:

```
//This program will format a gradebook
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void gradebook ( istream& in, ostream& out )
{
string firstname[2];
string lastname[2];
string dummy;
//header for table

int projwe;
int hwwe;
int attendwe;
int midwe;
int finalwe;
int attendgr[2];
int midgr[2];
int hwgr1[2];
int hwgr2[2];
int hwgr3[2];
int projgr1[2];
int projgr2[2];
int projgr3[2];
int finalgr[2];
int attendgrade;
int hwgrade1;
int hwgrade2;
int hwgrade3;
int projgrade1;
int projgrade2;
int projgrade3;
int midtermgrade;
int finalsgrade;
double averagegr;
//weights for each category

in >> dummy >> attendwe;
in >> dummy >> midwe;
in >> dummy >> finalwe;
in >> dummy >> hwwe;
in >> dummy >> projwe;
in >> firstname[2];
in >> lastname[2];
in >> dummy >> attendgr[2];
in >> dummy >> midgr[2];
in >> dummy >> hwgr1[2];
in >> dummy >> hwgr2[2];
in >> dummy >> hwgr3[2];
in >> dummy >> projgr1[2];
in >> dummy >> projgr2[2];
in >> dummy >> projgr3[2];
in >> dummy >> finalgr[2];
//loads words and weights into above variables

attendgrade = ( ( attendgr[0]*attendwe ) + ( attendgr[1]*attendwe ) )/2;
//calculates the overall attendance grade

hwgrade1 = ( ( hwgr1[0]*hwwe ) +  ( hwgr1[1]*hwwe ) ) /2;
hwgrade2 =  ( ( hwgr2[0]*hwwe ) +  ( hwgr2[1]*hwwe ) ) /2;
hwgrade3 =  ( ( hwgr3[0]*hwwe ) +  ( hwgr3[1]*hwwe ) ) /2;
//calculates the overall homework grade

projgrade1 = ( ( projgr1[0]*projwe ) + ( projgr1[1]*projwe ) ) /2;
projgrade2 = ( ( projgr2[0]*projwe ) + ( projgr2[1]*projwe ) ) /2;
projgrade3 = ( ( projgr3[0]*projwe ) + ( projgr3[1]*projwe ) ) /2;
//calculates the overall project grade

midtermgrade = ( ( midgr[0]*midwe ) + ( midgr[1]*midwe ) ) /2;
//calculates the overall midterm grade

finalsgrade = ( ( finalgr[0]*finalwe ) + ( finalgr[1]*finalwe ) ) /2;
//calculates the overall finals grade

averagegr = ( finalsgrade + midtermgrade + projgrade1 + projgrade2 + projgrade3 + hwgrade1 + hwgrade2 + hwgrade3 + attendgrade ) / 9;
//calculates the average grade

out << "LastName" << "," << "FirstName" << "," << "HW1" << "," << "HW2" << "," << "HW3" << "," 
<< "Proj1" << "," << "Proj2" << "," << "Proj3" << "," << "Midterm" << "," << "Final" << "," << "Average" << endl;
//outputs the header for the table

out << firstname << "," << lastname << "," << attendgrade << "," << hwgrade1 << "," << hwgrade2 << "," << hwgrade3 << ","
<< projgrade1 << "," << projgrade2 << "," << projgrade3 << "," << midtermgrade << "," << finalsgrade << "," << averagegr << endl;
//outputs the numbers in the table
}
```

Now I'm getting a weird error, which is in line 10 of the main:

```
error C2664: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ostream(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *,bool)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [11] to std::basic_streambuf<+Elem,_Traits> *'
```

Comment: You should post the code you have tried, otherwise this looks like a "write code for me" question.

Comment: You might also post the specifications of the input file.  I can't figure it out from the small sample you give.  (And the words prior to the numbers seem significant.  In which case, you don't want to skip them, but to read them as well.)

Comment: You can *not* write this much code all at once and expect it to work. Start small and simple, then build up, testing at every step. Anyway, it's not clear what you meant by `ostream out ( "grades.txt" );`, since you never use `out` again, but you can't construct an `ostream` that way. Maybe you meant `ofstream`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string dummy;
int n;
fin >> dummy >> n;
```

Comment: Off hand, it looks a little more difficult than that.  Although strictly speaking, that is the answer to his literal, it seems quite clear that there's more to it that he hasn't realized.  (What's going to happen on the `"Mc Pherson, David Patrick"` line, for example?)

Comment: @JamesKanze: This is not a compete solution, of course, but it's enough to get the OP started. If the OP gets stuck after *putting in some effort* with this much, we can give more detailed answers.

Comment: I tried what he said, but I'm getting a weird error from my main.cpp. I'll post my code in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to guess the format: would it be a header, with the
weights of each element, followed by records with a name, and
a number of results, each result specified by a *elementtype*
_n_ *m*, where the element type refers to the element given in
the header, *n* the number of points for this evaluation, and
*m* the maximum number of points.  In this case, the best
solution is probably to parse line by line, then search for the
`':'`.  If there is no `':'`, it's a name, otherwise, you have
to parse:

```
std::string name;
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( fin, line ) ) {
    std::string::const_iterator colon = std::find( line.begin(), line.end(), ':' );
    if ( colon == line.end() ) {
        name = line;
    } else if ( name.empty() ) {
        parseHeaderLine( std::string( line.begin(), colon ), std::string( colon + 1, line.end() ) );
    } else {
        parseDataLine( name, std::string( line.begin(), colon ), std::string( colon + 1, line.end() ) );
    }
}
```

As for the parsing, you can use `std::istringstream` on the two
parts of the line.